# Bounty on a question with an unsatisfactory answer

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have just put a bounty on the question [Floor function not returning correct value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/241592/35000)

I wrote there

```
The existing answer is not satisfactory, as explained in a comment.
I find this issue important. There is no satisfactory answer.
```

After that I realized that if there will be no reaction, the bounty will go to the existing answer which, as I said, is not satisfactory in my opinion.

Can one do anything sensible in such cases?

Comment: It doesn't look like an answer is actually selected as "the answer". So, I'm guessing the bounty won't go to any of the answers until one is selected.

Comment: Found this in the FAQs: You may not cancel a bounty once it has been started.

Comment: @lericr There are now several answers to choose from there, but if there would remain a single answer, would not the bounty automatically go to it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how bounties work, but I would think that the bounty supplier would need to explicitly accept a particular answer. Actually, now that I think about it, I'm positive I've seen bounties expire even though answers were provided.

Comment: My previous comment doesn't read well. I understand that you're thinking singular answser versus multiple answers. What I was getting at is that I don't see any difference in how bounties are applied versus how "regular" answers are given approval. So, I strongly suspect that the singular versus multiple doesn't matter.